# What is a word for when you understand and comprehend something but cannot do it?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, poetry, do, thought

Emily Dickinson understands all the concepts of poetry but cannot write all her thoughts.

Comment: A few idioms and expressions come to mind, like "Knowing and doing are two separate things," "Emily Dickinson would've been a good teacher, because those who can, do, but those who can't, teach." "Emily Dickinson understood it all, but when the rubber met the road, she fell flat."

Comment: Sounds like *book learning*.

Comment: Maybe not the *actual* "answer", but [*A consultant is a eunuch: he **wants** to, he **knows how** to, but he **can't actually do it**.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31861/126)

Comment: Teacher ;) Although academic is probably a more acceptable answer.